# Pure braid groups of the complement of a lattice in the complex plane: generators and relations

Tags: reference-request, gt.geometric-topology, braid-groups

Where can I find a presentation (by `natural' generators and relations between them) 
of the pure braid groups $PB_n(S)$ (for $n>0$) of $S=\mathbb C\setminus (\mathbb Z\oplus i \mathbb Z)$?

Thanks in advance.